# Get stylesheet tag that styles specific node

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible with javascript to get the stylesheet tag that styles specific node? 
for example if i have this html page:

```
<head>
<style>
.someclass {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="someclass"></div>
</body>
```

can i detect and get which stylesheet styles the div node?

Comment: No, unless you want to go through every style being applied.

Comment: Yes is it possible, will print an answer in a few minutes..

Comment: You can get all stylesheets and loop over all their rules. `querySelectorAll` would allow you to check if the target element is matched by such a rule. But you would still have to take things like specificity and probable occurrences of stuff like `!important` into account to determine where a specific style actually originates. Quite broad as a question, can you narrow down the purpose of what you would actually need this for?

Comment: @misorude I'm having problem with some of the nodes in my website when the adblock extention is present , my nodes classes contains the word "targeting" which is blacklisted on some filter lists , the problem occurs when i'm checking the node "display" css rule to see if it's none or not (because i'm setting it to none after some logic) but because the adblock injected css rules also set it to none my entire code logic is messed up. so i would like to know which stylesheet set its value

Answer (score 0):

If you asking this for debugging purposes, i should say use the debug screen of your browser. Usually F12.

If you asking this in order the display/get the stylesheet that is applying trough Javascript you can do this with:

```
document.styleSheets
```

This will return the CSSStyleSheet interface, beware this is still stage 2 experimental technology. In order to get the right rule and its owner you have to program it.